# Click events and Google Chrome and Windows 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am trying to use the following JQuery code:

```
$("#thing").on("click", function() {
....})
```

And it doesn't work on Google Chrome in Windows 8, but it works in Firefox on Windows 8 and basically every other OS. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try using `bind` but I highly not encourage this ...

Comment: @DavidBélanger there is no reason to use .bind() over .on(), both work the same in this case

Comment: @roasted Yes, you are right.

Comment: It doesn't look wrong... but it's also not a bad idea to declare the closest appropriate parent for $.on() to reduce DOM travel, like $("#things_closest_parent").on("click", "#thing", function(){...}). Have you console logged the event to see if it's something in your callback that's messing it up?

Answer (score 1):

It works, check this: http://jsbin.com/ofuvuh/1 Probably there is some error in the code that ff ignore or maybe it's your browsers fault. Please check the chrome and ie console, probably it can helps

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#thing").click(function ()
{
    // your code here
});
```

Which is the same as `.on('click', handler)`. See [.click documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: Also, does the demo on the bottom of http://api.jquery.com/click/ work in your browser? If not, it **might** be some kind of jQuery/browser bug.

Comment: R I strongly doubt that the bug is with the browser or jQuery. It will be something to do with some other parts of the code.

Comment: @heartcode And I doubt the example in the official documentation won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet looks completely fine. I assume you are using a fairly up to date version of jQuery, so most probably it is nothing to do with jQuery or the browser. I suspect there might be something wrong with the code surrounding your snippet.

As a possible solution:
In Chrome you can bring up the `Console`, which will tell you if there is any errors in your JavaScript (developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/…). Open it up, refresh your page (you might see the error in the Console straight away). Or click that '#thing' and watch out for any possible errors coming up in the `Console`.